# Как добавить класс к div и убрать только при наведении на другой div

Tags: jquery

Есть несколько элементов, при наведении на блок(A) нужно показать блок(B), но убрать блок(B), только тогда, когда мы наведем на блок(С), а при наведении на блок(С), показать блок(D)

Comment: Дмитрий, подскажите, что пробовали уже делать сами? А так же распишите, пожалуйста вопрос подробнее. Блок (А) всегда виден? остальные блоки в каком порядке хотите показывать и скрывать? Например, при наведении на блок (D) будет ли скрываться блок (C), и в тоже время блок (B) останется скрытым?

Comment: Родитель это блок(С), дочерний блок(D), при наведении, например, на родительский блок(C), нужно рядом показать дочерний блок(D), а убрать его, только тогда, когда мы наведем на другой родительский блок

Comment: Вы всё же не ответили на первый мой вопрос. Можете показать, что пробовали уже делать сами? То есть структура вложенности следующая A->B->C->D->E...? Тогда какой другой родительский блок Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Нет, структура другая

То есть, A - родитель A1-дочерний, при наведении на блок А, нужно показать дочерний блок A1

Структура такая: А>А1; B>B1; C>C1 и т.д.

Comment: Это сообщество помощи программистов - программистам. Если Вы не пытаетесь разобраться в вопросе или хотя бы как-то решить его самостоятельно - Вам никто помогать не станет. Так как это первый Ваш вопрос на данном портале - в качестве исключения добавил ответ. В дальнейшем обязательно выкладывайте самостоятельные попытки решения задачи.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Хорошее замечание сделали в комментарии - добавил вариант с наведением на элемент, а не по клику.(снизу)

Answer (score 4):

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

        for(let i=0;i<parent.length;i++){
            parent[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                for(let z=0;z<parent.length;z++){
                    parent[z].children[0].style.display = "none";
                }
                this.children[0].style.display = "block";
            })
        }
    }
```

```css
    .toogle{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="A" class="text">Нажми A
    <div id="B" class="toogle">Получим результат B</div>
</div>

<div id="C" class="text">Нажми C
    <div id="D" class="toogle">Получим результат D</div>
</div>

<div id="E" class="text">Нажми E
    <div id="F" class="toogle">Получим результат F</div>
</div>
```

Если необходимо при наведении:

```js
   window.onload = function () {
        var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

        for(let i=0;i<parent.length;i++){
            parent[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                for(let z=0;z<parent.length;z++){
                    parent[z].children[0].style.display = "none";
                }
                this.children[0].style.display = "block";
            })
        }
    }
```

```css
    .toogle{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="A" class="text">Нажми A
    <div id="B" class="toogle">Получим результат</div>
</div>

<div id="C" class="text">Нажми C
    <div id="D" class="toogle">Получим результат</div>
</div>

<div id="E" class="text">Нажми D
    <div id="F" class="toogle">Получим результат</div>
</div>
```

Comment: В задаче сказано "по наведению", а у Вас по клику - ??

Comment: @humster_spb Спасибо за замечание, добавил.